# Yukawa theory: Fermion-Antifermion scattering

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, fourier-transform, feynman-diagrams

I have the following Yukawa theory: $$\mathcal{L} =\frac{1}{2}\partial_{\mu}\phi \partial^{\mu} \phi-\frac{1}{2}M\phi^2+\bar\psi(i\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}-m)\psi-g\bar{\psi}\psi\phi$$

and a fermion-antifermion scattering, that is $$\psi\bar{\psi}\rightarrow \psi\bar{\psi}.$$
The initial momentums and spins are $(p,s)$ for the fermion, and $(q,r)$ for the antifermion, while the final momentums and spins are $(p^\prime, s^\prime)$ for the fermion and $(q^\prime, r^\prime)$ for the antifermion. The fields are quantized as

$$\psi(x) = \int\frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^{\frac{3}{2}}\sqrt{2w_p}}\sum_{s}(b_{p,s}u_s(p)e^{-ipx}+d_{p,s}^\dagger v_{s}(p)e^{ipx})$$

$$\hat{\psi}(x) = \int\frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^{\frac{3}{2}}\sqrt{2w_p}}\sum_{s}(b_{p,s}^\dagger\bar{u}_{s}(p)e^{ipx}+d_{p,s}\bar{v}_{s}(p)e^{-ipx})$$

$$\phi(x) =\int\frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^{\frac{3}{2}}\sqrt{2w_p}}(a_p e^{-ipx}+a_p^\dagger e^{ipx}).$$

I found that one of the contributions to the $S$-matrix is the following:

$$\frac{(-ig)^2}{2!}\int d^4x d^4y e^{i p^\prime x}\bar{u}(p^\prime, s^\prime) e^{i q^\prime x} v_(q^\prime, r^\prime) e^{-iqy}\bar{v}(q,r) e^{-ipy}u(p,s)i\hbar \Delta_F(x-y).$$ Can someone help me computing the Feynman diagram of this contribution?